# Remainder when dividing biggest prime (with distinct digits) below $100000$ by $37$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any way to find this value in a **non-brute-force** manner? This question appeared on a timed exam on which one was allowed to use a computer and write programs, but there simply wasn't enough time. My intuition says that the only way is to actually find this prime, but there may exist some mathematical properties I am not aware of.

Comment: That's typically a question that would appear in an algorithm exam. It seems really unlikely that analytical properties could give informations on the biggest prime with distinct digits below 100000.

Comment: What do you mean when you say “distinct digits”? Does not the prime number contain two equal digits? Or does the prime number contain at least two different digits?

Comment: By distinct digits I mean a number that doesn't contain the same digit twice. This constraint actually led me to believe that an analytic answer is quite unlikely, but I thought it was worthy to ask this anyway.

Comment: I agree that there is no better way than brute force (checking the possible numbers in decreasing order whether they are prime until a prime is found). Of course, we can slightly refine the search (for example, the ending digit must be $1,3,7$ or $9$ and the digit sum cannot be divisible by $3$), but apart from this we cannot do any better.

Comment: Does there exist a non-brute-force way to know if $1111111111111111111$ is prime ? The number of $1$’s is $19$.

Comment: The first three digits will be 987..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is not a non-brute-force way to solve your exercise, but the good news is that actually there are not a lot of cases and only in one case there is a prime divisor greater than $19$.

$98765\;$ is divisible by $\;5\;$.

$98764\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98763\;$ is divisible by $\;3\;$.

$98762\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98761\;$ is divisible by $\;13\;$.

$98760\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98756\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98754\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98753\;$ is divisible by $\;17\;$.

$98752\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98751\;$ is divisible by $\;3\;$.

$98750\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98746\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98745\;$ is divisible by $\;3\;$.

$98743\;$ is divisible by $\;19\;$.

$98742\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98741\;$ is divisible by $\;293\;$.

$98740\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98736\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98735\;$ is divisible by $\;5\;$.

$98734\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98732\;$ is divisible by $\;2\;$.

$98731\;$ is prime.

Since $\;98731=2668\cdot37+15\;,\;$ the remainder of the division $\;98731 : 37\;$ is $\;15\;$.

Answer (score 1):

According to Empy2's comment, let start $987ab.$
Since $98700  \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then exclude $(a,b)$ such that $a+b  \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$
Further, last digit must be $1$ or $3.$
Let pick up $(a,b)=(6,1),(5,3),(4,1),(4,3),(3,1),(2,3),(1,3)$, then we know $98731$ is prime number.